# Throw a value error in the main thread from a callback

Tags: javascript, callback, throw

I'm a beginner to JavaScript and I have a lot of difficulties to throw a message error in my main thread when there an error occurs in a third-party asynchronous function:

```js
function mainThread(){
   try{
         myFunction(param1, error => {
            throw error // Error is not catched
         })
      }
   catch (error)
   {
      "i would like to catch the error here in the main thread"
   }
}


function myFunction(param1, callback) {
    asyncThirdpartyfunction(param1, (err) => {
        if (err)
            callback(err)
         
    })
}
```

The error is thrown in my console without be handled by the catch.
What is wrong? What shall I do to get the error value in my main thread?
I tried a lot of things with callback and promise, but they didn't do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If `asyncThirdpartyfunction` returns a promise, you can use `catch` to handle errors:

```
asyncThirdpartyfunction(param1, (err) => {
    if (err)
        callback(err)
     
})
.catch(err => alert(err))
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I have tested your example and i have an error : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined"

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you either use promises or `async/await`.

With promises your example would look like:

```js
function mainThread() {
  myFunction("Some data")
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error is ", error);
  });
}

function myFunction(param1) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    asyncThirdpartyfunction(param1, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

function asyncThirdpartyfunction(param, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback("Error"));
}

mainThread()
```

Here we more or less "convert" the third party function into a `Promise`.

You could also use `async/await` which would look something like:

```js
async function mainThread() {
  try {
    const result = await myFunction("some data");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error is ", error);
  }
}

async function myFunction(param1) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    asyncThirdpartyfunction(param1, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

function asyncThirdpartyfunction(param, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback("Error"));
}

mainThread()
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I write as your example but the difference that i would like to do is to "throw" an error instead of "log in the console". And currently when throwing in the catch it said in the console: "Unhandled rejection at Promise".  I need to throw and not log, as there is a ecosystem behind that handle the error and do many things. How can i workaround the issue?